# terrainData.heightmapHeight doesn't fit with heightmapResolution

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

As far as i know the `terrainData.heightmapResolution` should affect the `terrainData.heightmapHeight`.

So if i set the `terrainData.heightmapResolution` to `241`, the `terrainData.heightmapHeight` becomes `257` and i can't figure out why.

if i want to set the `terrainData.heightmapResolution` to `(241 - 16)`, the `terrainData.heightmapHeight` still becomes `257`.

What i would need is that the `terrainData.heightmapHeight` becomes `241`, but i can't figure out how to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heightmaps need to have a height and width of a whole power of 2 plus 1.

257 is a valid height/width because 257 = 256 + 1  = 2^8 + 1.

241 is not a valid height/width because there's no integer n such that 241 = 2^n + 1

Comment: ah okay i see, then i will rework my script to use 257, thanks!

Comment: just changed it in my script to use 257 and it works fine now!